`NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=19384` is not working properly in my azure devops build pipeline
Frontend Build Pipeline:
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Job
        pool:
          vmImage: windows-latest
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '16.13.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'

          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'npm install --verbose'
            inputs:
              script: |
                npm install --verbose
          - script: |
              npm cache clean --force
            displayName: 'npm Cache clean'


          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'npm build'
            env:
              NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=19384
            inputs:
              script: |
                npm run build

          - task: whitesource.WhiteSource-azure-devops-services.bolt.wss.WhiteSource@21
            inputs:
              cwd: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:
              Contents: 'web.config'
              TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: 'build'
              ArtifactName: 'drop'
              publishLocation: 'Container'

Many times the pipeline is failing for the below error:
#[warning]Free memory is lower than 5%; Currently used: 96.87%
##[warning]Free memory is lower than 5%; Currently used: 96.87%
##[warning]Free memory is lower than 5%; Currently used: 96.87%
##[warning]Free memory is lower than 5%; Currently used: 96.87%
##[warning]Free memory is lower than 5%; Currently used: 96.87%
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-1073740791'.


Even If i try with self hosted agent to build the code in the above pipeline, the same error is coming twice in a day.
In the GitHub Issues, I can see this option NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size is no longer supported.
How do I resolve this issue?

If you’re using a self-hosted agent, consider upgrading the VM size to one with more memory, especially if the current one has 8 GB or less. Another troubleshooting you can do is- in your npm run build command, prepend node --expose-gc to enable manual garbage collection and within your build scripts, add global.gc(); calls at strategic points to release memory proactively.

Hi @Arko, We are using the Microsoft Hosted Agents not the self hosted.

what image? ubuntu? go for ubuntu it has lower memory overhead compared to Windows.

Approximately how much memory does it take to build your project? If it's close to the memory of the MS-hosted agent, you can add --optimize-for-size before build to your package.json, which is used for optimizing memory. For example, "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096  --optimize-for-size  ./node_modules/.bin/craco build --verbose".

Image is Windows-latest, Microsoft hosted pipelines and the artifacts size is approximately 78 MB and in some builds varies from 40 MB to 80 MB.

Have you tried adding --optimize-for-size before build to your package.json? Did it work for you?

I have not added. Instead of this, the dev team has tried to remove unwanted files from the code and the issue has been sorted.

@VivekAnandChakravarthy did you resolve the issue? any solution for self hosted agent?
